# provide alternative name to the original name in solr while searching

Tags: xml, solr, indexing

I've 100 documents like this

```
<doc>
<field name="id">9</field>
<field name="riskId">4</field>
<field name="riskType">legal</field>
<field name="riskValue">3</field>
<field name="product">Router CTP133</field>
<field name="facility">plant</field>
<field name="location">Busan, korea</field>
</doc>
```

currently if i search for Router("//XYZ:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=router"), i get result if the word "Router is present in "product" field. but i want to query in other way like...if i search for RT("//XYZ:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=RT"), i should get the same result.

Please help me out. I've got this requirement to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess (and let me know if I'm wrong), that your `product` field is being indexed as a `type="text"` field. If that's the case, you have a good solution handy. Your analysis for the text fieldType (configured in `schema.xml`) should include this line for both index and query-time analysis:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
```

This allows you to establish a set of known synonyms that should be identified within the `synonyms.txt` file in your index's `conf` folder. For instance, one line in your `synonyms.txt` file might read:

```
router => rt
```

When you provide the value "Router CTP133" as a product name, it will actually be indexed as "rt ctp 133". (Note, I'm making the assumption that you have other common text-field filtering configured.) When someone searches for "rt" it will match this modified product name. If someone searches for "router", the `SynonymFilterFactory` will step in again and modify the search. Instead of "router," the search that's *actually applied* will be "rt". So it will match regardless.

If you make the necessary change to your `synonyms.txt` file, and to your `schema.xml` (if synonym filtering isn't already activated), you should be able to re-index your documents to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Thnanks, i got it but this answer is needed small correction. instead of "router => rt", write "rt => router".

Comment: Both orders should have the same effect if applied at both query and index time. With `rt => router`, you could get away with applying the filter only when querying, as long as the abbreviation "rt" doesn't appear in any actual product records.

Comment: i tried again the way you said. But its not working. Probably I'm going wrong somewhere. And anyway i meeting my requirements.

Comment: @ frances: can you please look at this. I've another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822503/solr-multiple-pdf-files-indexing-all-at-once